# A synonym for "over" in "over a distance"

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

Could you give me the best synonym for *over* in this situation?

> Aqueduct: artificial channel for conducting water over a distance.

I know it is the best preposition for this context. But I wonder if there's a synonym for it and its definition.

Comment: What's wrong with *over*? That's the usual word to use. (Please [edit the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/152812/edit) to add that explanation)

Comment: You could use *across* but *over* seems more natural. What's the problem?

Comment: One case when a synonym would be desireable would be if you'd already used the word "over" nearby. For example "Aqueduct: artificial channel for conducting water over a distance overland" sounds a little clunky.

Comment: The word "over" doesn't really contribute anything to the semantics anyway. I could say, for example, *"A supermarket trolley is only suitable for transporting groceries a short distance"*.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "**[along](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/along)**" also but "over" is still a better fit.

> *prep*
>   **1.** over or for the length of, esp in a more or less horizontal plane: *along the road.*

Comment: What about covering?

Comment: @nima_persian

covering doesn't sound natural here. Looks like if you are going to use "covering", you should include the measurement as well